# Appcelerator (Titanium mobile) sample project(Movie) does not run

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I just started Appcelerator (titanium mobile). I downloaded Appcelerator studio and then I tried to launch a sample project "Movie" but I got this error below..

I run for iPhone6 device and it seems that UncrustifyPlugin does not work but no ideas what should I do.

```
[ERROR] :  2015-09-26 23:09:14.901 xcodebuild[49683:1449584] WARNING: Failed to load plugin at path: "/Users/yusaku/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin", skipping. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “UncrustifyPlugin” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." (dlopen_preflight(/Users/yusaku/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/UncrustifyPlugin): no suitable image found.  Did find:
[ERROR] :   /Users/yusaku/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/UncrustifyPlugin: code signature invalid for '/Users/yusaku/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/UncrustifyPlugin'
[ERROR] :  ) UserInfo=0x7fa8ebbe0120 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/yusaku/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/UncrustifyPlugin, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/yusaku/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/UncrustifyPlugin): no suitable image found.  Did find:
[ERROR] :   /Users/yusaku/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/UncrustifyPlugin: code signature invalid for '/Users/yusaku/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/UncrustifyPlugin'
[ERROR] :  , NSBundlePath=/Users/yusaku/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “UncrustifyPlugin” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Movies.build/Debug-iphoneos/Movies-universal.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Movies normal arm64
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Movies.build/Debug-iphoneos/Movies-universal.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Movies normal armv7
[ERROR] :  (2 failures)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

---

update1

I deleted all of plugins in Plug-ins folder.

```
/Users/hoge/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins
```

And then I got another error...

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Movies.build/Debug-iphoneos/Movies-universal.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Movies normal armv7
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/hoge/.appcelerator/install/5.0.2/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:89:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
```

No clues....

My XCode is latest. XCode7、Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.3.0

---

update2

I found this project file.

```
/Users/hoge/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Movies/build/iphone/Movies.xcodeproj
```

The following error occurred when I launched on XCode.

```
ld: '/Users/hoge/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Movies/build/iphone/lib/libti_ios_profiler.a(TiProfilerDiscovery.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

update3

Turned off bitcode and then running was OK on XCode. I will try on Appcelerator.

---

update4

I think that Appcelerator 4.3.0 is not compatible for iOS9, XCode. I lost 2 hours... How can I upadte it.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/release-notes/?version=5.0.0.GA

---

update5

I installed the latest SDK thanks to @miga but still my Appcelerator studio is version 4.3. Why...!?

And now I noticed this message "Version 5.0.2 already installed." ... what's that?

Actually still not sure this question "Do you plan on developing Titanium apps?"

```
$ appc setup

Finding latest version ...5.0.2 ✓

Version 5.0.2 already installed.

? Do you plan on developing Titanium apps? Yes

Checking your environment...

A new version of the Titanium SDK is available, will download it...

New version available! 5.0.1.GA

Downloading http://builds.appcelerator.com/mobile-releases/5.0.1/mobilesdk-5.0.1.GA-osx.zip

  100% [========================================] 0.5s    

Extracting SDK to /Users/hoge/Library/Application Support/Titanium

  100% [========================================] 0.0s 

Setting Titanium SDK 5.0.1.GA as the default.

Titanium SDK 5.0.1.GA successfully installed!

Congrats! No issues detected for developing cross-platform mobile apps!

appc setup complete!
```

---

update6 final

I changed tiapp.xml

from

```
<sdk-version>3.5.1.RC</sdk-version>
```

to

```
<sdk-version>5.0.1.GA</sdk-version>
```

then I could install the app in my iPhone device finally!

I think I changed from 5.0.1.GA to 5.0.2 as the default. But 5.0.2 must be better than 5.0.1.GA. ***How can I change again!?***

I was refused when I set 5.0.2...

```
<sdk-version>5.0.2</sdk-version>
```

I suppose I didn't need to install 5.0.1.GA. Just I needed changing tiapp.xml. I wasted my time for 4 hours..

Comment: @miga updating now! Thanks! I will let you know the result.

Comment: welcome to appcelerator, this won't be unusual :)

Comment: @Robert Dupuy Hi. I found the registration fee was $39 per month... Is it right? Some people say we can use it without charge. I think I can not pay for the cost....

Comment: @zono Yes, my understanding is the cost is $39 per month.  Although, developers that were signed up before the new pricing scheme (and who requested the indie program before the deadline) are on a free program.  But, at least so far the new App Designer doesn't look like its available for the $39 per month program, so it looks like soon it'll be $3,108 per year, for those that need the App Designer visual ui builder.